# Why do I get an error for comparing two array elements with operator<, even though I have already overloaded the operator <?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

-The errors that keep occurring:

- expected primary-expression before '[' token
- expected primary-expression before '[' token

```
void selectionSort(Blog blog[], int numBlogs)
{
    Blog temp;
    int minIndex=0;
    for (int i=0; i<numBlogs-1; i++)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j<numBlogs; j++)
        if (Blog[j] < Blog[minIndex]) //this is where the error occurs
                minIndex=j;     //swap positions i and minIndex
        temp = blog[i];
        blog[i] = blog[minIndex];
        blog[minIndex] = temp;
        displayBlogs(blog, numBlogs);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You aren't comparing two arrays. You are comparing two array *elements,* or trying to.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison is comparing against the *type* `Blog` instead of the object `blog` (note the case difference). Comparing against `Blog[j]` is a syntax error since this is the type and not the instance.

This should be:

```cpp
if (blog[j] < blog[minIndex]) //change to lowercase b
```

Comment: I changed "Blog" to "blog" and now I get this error: [Error] no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'Blog' and 'Blog')

Comment: @HaydenHibbett that means the `Blog` type doesn't have an `operator<` implemented yet, so you will have to create one. You can't just compare arbitrary user-defined types by default, only fundamental types have default operators defined.